# HTTP Status 404 – The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

[please help me in running spring framework project. i followed the crunchify tutorial however it failed][1]

[crunchify tutorial][1]

[Error in Eclipse Oxygen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aakjb.png)

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: A spring mvc hello world failed to run on server. I followed step by step Crunchify tutorial however it did not work. 
I am getting 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

the issue occurring because of `crunchify-servlet.xml`  file. `crunchify-servlet.xml` having some error you need to solve this issue before running the project. and erro 404 occur because requested page is not found or bad url. check your `web.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you very much for response.Please suggest correct tutorial for Spring MVC.